# Element.getAttribute() returning promisestatus as Pending : protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

**My Statement**

```
var data = elmnt.getAttribute('row-id').then(function(value){
    rowid = value
    callback();
}); 
console.log('global var inside Rowid:'+ rowid);
console.log('global var inside data:'+ data);
```

**My Output**:

> global var inside Rowid:null global var inside
>   data:ManagedPromise::19682 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

can someone please help

Comment: `.then()`? Why? `getAttribute` doesn't return a promise, it's synchronous.

Comment: @mbojko I think it does! I think it should resolve and if the attribute doesn't exist the value should be null. Please move the console.logs in the callback function, it might help

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri tried that as well but its not going inside the promise

Comment: Thats just weird. Maybe you can post your configuration, the component files, anything that might help!

Comment: config is similar to below git repo: https://github.com/Marketionist/protractor-cucumber-steps/blob/master/tests/protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, sorry, didn't notice the `protractor` tag.

So, if we have a promisified `getAttribute`, then that's how you consume promises:

```
elmnt.getAttribute('row-id').then(function(rowId) {
    console.log(rowId);
});
```

You need to do it inside the promise chain. `console.log(somePromise)` will only log a promise, not a value, and `console.log(rowid)` before the promise is resolved will produce `null`/`undefined`.

Comment: its not giving any output using this as i believe promise is not fulfilled